# java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack in method com.sun.net.httpserver.spi.HttpServerProvider

Tags: java, ant, bytecode

I have been plagued by this problem and managed to narrow it down to a small file that **fails** throwing the `java.lang.VerifyError` when invoked from Ant with `fork` set to `false` in the `<java>` task but **succeeds** when `fork` is set to `true`.

The self-contained file is:

```
package foo;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
class Hello  {
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}


public class FooMain {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Object implementor = new Hello();
        String address = "http://localhost:9000/SoapContext/SoapPort";
        Endpoint.publish(address, implementor);
    }
}
```

When invoked with Ant and `fork` set to `false` it throws:

```
 [java] java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
 [java] Exception Details:
 [java]   Location:
 [java]     com/sun/net/httpserver/spi/HttpServerProvider$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object; @27: invokestatic
 [java]   Reason:
 [java]     Type 'sun/net/httpserver/DefaultHttpServerProvider' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/sun/net/httpserver/spi/HttpServerProvider'
 [java]   Current Frame:
 [java]     bci: @27
 [java]     flags: { }
 [java]     locals: { 'com/sun/net/httpserver/spi/HttpServerProvider$1' }
 [java]     stack: { 'sun/net/httpserver/DefaultHttpServerProvider' }
 [java]   Bytecode:
 [java]     0000000: b800 2599 0007 b800 27b0 b800 2699 0007
 [java]     0000010: b800 27b0 bb00 1a59 b700 2ab8 0028 57b8
 [java]     0000020: 0027 b0                                
 [java]   Stackmap Table:
 [java]     same_frame(@10)
```

When invoked with `fork` set to `true` it succeeds. The specific exception `VerifyError` especially when combined with "`Bad type on operand stack`" points to a compiler bug from what I've read but why should it succeed or fail depending on the `fork` attribute of the `<java>` Ant task is beyond me. Any thoughts? I am running `Ubuntu 12.04` with the following java tools:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_40
$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
$ ant -diagnostics | grep java.vm
java.vm.version : 24.0-b56
java.vm.vendor : Oracle Corporation
java.vm.name : Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM
java.vm.specification.name : Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor : Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version : 1.7
java.vm.info : mixed mode
```

## important update

When invoked from Ant with `fork` set to `false` I also have to explicitly add `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/rt.jar` to the CLASSPATH in order to trigger the `VerifyError` exception. Otherwise it fails before reaching that point with:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
```

Of course having to add `rt.jar` in the CLASSPATH is mighty strange especially since it is the `rt.jar` of the `java` version I am using.

Comment: What does `ant -diagnostics | grep java.vm` say?

Comment: This is very likely due to a jar file mismatch or some such.

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely due to the mismatch between java versions, I see you are running 1.7.0_40 and 1.7.0_24.  Ensure JAVA_HOME is set to the 1.7.0_40 JDK prior to invoking Ant.  See the following post for additional information on how to do that. [How do I change the JAVA_HOME for ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573235/how-do-i-change-the-java-home-for-ant)

Comment: Actually, that's the VM version, sorry about that.  Are you sure that java executable is is the one that's being executed?  What's the value of JAVA_HOME and what does `which javac` and `which java` produce?  Is the target a symbolic link?  If so then where does it point?

Comment: you are right, jar was made up by 1.8 and i was running it with 1.7

Answer (score 2):

Well, most likely, it just is a **compiler bug**, see http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8006684

And it does not really depend on the fork property as per your description, only the classpath does.

Answer (score 0):

When the class is loaded some verification procedures are performed. If byte code was generated with errors classloader could raise a VerifyError.

I had the same issue. To solve it:

1. Update Java. On the build environment and on the execution environment. Should be over `1.8.0_75`
2. Update CGLIB if used in your project dependencies. `2.2` -> `3.2.4` solved the issue.