# Issue with adding Java to PATH on a local machine

Tags: java, path

I have a rather trivial issue for which I cannot find a solution. I have two versions of Java installed on my local machine namely jdk1.5.0_16 and jdk1.7.0_80, both residing under Program Files. I want to use jdk1.5.0_16 in my Path. But even after I change my path to include jdk1.5.0_16, running "java -version" in command prompt returns jdk 1.7.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here or how can I change it to point to jdk1.5.0_16?

Comment: Can you show us your path? You added it at the end? If so, you have to add it to the beginning...

Comment: How did you change the path?

Comment: Take care of the order of the paths. When searching for a valid JDK, the system will take the first entry it finds.

Comment: My Path is - %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

Comment: I only have one version of java i.e. jdk1.5.0_16 added in my path

Comment: So your `echo %JAVA_HOME%` prints jdk1.5.0_16 ?

Answer (score 0):

Open `cmd` and type `set p` it will print all variables starting with p. You can do the same with `set java`.

Comment: I am building my project using Ant which takes the JAVA_HOME from environment variables. So need to change it in path

Comment: Maybe you want to check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573235/how-do-i-change-the-java-home-for-ant